# c++ strcmp returns 0 even though the strings are same.pls explain why?

Tags: c++, string

this is the code to check whether the string is palindrome or not.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   char a[20]="",b[20]="";
   int len,c;
   cout<<"Enter the string";
   cin>>a;
   len=strlen(a);
   cout<<len<<endl;

   for(int i=len-1,j=0;i>=0,j<=len;i--,j++)
   {
      b[i]=a[j];
   }
   cout<<a<<endl;
   cout<<b<<endl;
   cout<<strlen(b);
   c=strcmp(a,b);
   cout<<c<<endl;

   if(a==b)
   {
      cout<<"palindrome";
   }
}
```

in the above code if the input is sas the output should be palindrome. But it is not working pls say what is the error.

Comment: Please look at the documentation for strcmp.  It returns zero on success.

Comment: [stcrcmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

Comment: `if(a==b)` doesn't do what you think, `i>=0,j<=len` neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The strcmp function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero,
>   accordingly as the string pointed to by s1 is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by s2.

So equal strings will return 0.